# PHP stdClass object - adding element not working

Tags: php

I have a problem, I fetched all the rows from DB using PDO::FETCH_OBJ.
The response is completely okay. But I would like to loop through it and add an element with name 'photo' to each object in the array. This photo will include a small image converted to string.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $row->photo = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/xxx/uploads/'.$row->id.'/'.$row->filepath.'_thumbnail.jpg');
}
```

Pictures are being found without any problems, and even after I echo their content after I add it to $row, I get their contents without any problem too. But when I return the $rows variable, and I try to receive it in Android, the photo element is never there. What could be the problem?

This is how i return:

```
return base64_encode(json_encode($rows));
```

Example of output:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (10) {
  ["position"]=>  string(1) "1"
  ["id"]=>  string(2) "24"
  ["fbname"]=>  string(12) "Vl Mar"
  ["filepath"]=>  string(13) "1481809734438"
  ["photo"]=>  string(5760) "������JFIF���� .....and many more characters
}
```

Formatting at the end of output is not important, as its not Base64 decoded.

Comment: can we see an example of the output?

Comment: sure, done.....

Comment: `var_dump($rows)`? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry, you got it there.. I put the var_dump after I define $row->photo

Comment: put it before `json_encode`.

Comment: The same, the $row->photo is still there.

Comment: I honestly don't understand how you can even `json_encode` even part of that object. Since `photo` isn't a utf-8 string `json_encode` should returns `null`. Please, provide us an example that we can replicate.

Comment: I need to return 10 images at once from my webservice. How should I do it then?